# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "f1"

Tags: java, casting

Estoy estudiando programación Java por el libro Java Para Novatos. Realizando un ejercicio donde debo programar un convertidor de divisas me topé con un problema que no le hayo solución debido a mi inexperiencia.

Cuando ejecuto el código me da como error:

> could not find main class ConversorDivisas.

Éste es el código que tengo:

````
//es un convertidor de divisas con un metodo main para comprobar que funciona.
//convierte de euros a libras y viceversa.**
```
package Ejercicios;

public class ConversorDivisas {

    private double tipoCambio;
    public String getTipoCambio;

    //Constructor sin parámetros**
    public ConversorDivisas() {
        tipoCambio = 0.85;
    }
    //Constructor parametrizado**
    public ConversorDivisas(double tc) {
        tipoCambio = tc;
    }
    public double librasToEuros(double l) {
        return l * tipoCambio; 
    }
    public double eurosToLibras(double e) {
        return e / tipoCambio;
    }
    public void setTipoCambio(double tc){
        tipoCambio = tc;
    }
    public double getTipoCambio(){
        return tipoCambio;
    }
}
class PruebaDivisas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Que tipo de cambio quieres?");

        //a partir de aqui comienzan mis dudas**
        double tipo;
        tipo = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine());
        //con f1 utilizará el tipo de cambio de 0.85.**
        ConversorDivisas f1 = new ConversorDivisas();

        //con f2 se podrá modificar el tipo de cambio.**
        ConversorDivisas f2 = new ConversorDivisas(tipo);
        double e = 100;
        double l = 100;

        System.out.println("Con el tipo de cambio" + f1.getTipoCambio + ":");
        System.out.println(e + " euros son" + f1.eurosToLibras(0) + " libras");
        System.out.println(l + " libras" + f1.librasToEuros(0) + " euros");
        System.out.println("Con el tipo de cambio" + f2.getTipoCambio + ":");
        System.out.println(e + " euros son" + f2.eurosToLibras(0) + " libras");
        System.out.println(l + " libras son" + f2.librasToEuros(0) + " libras");
    }
}
````

---

En la siguiente imagen se muestra como me devuelve otro error, luego de hacer los cambios que me fueron recomendados:

[[image: En la imagen se muestra como me devuelve otro error, luego de hacer los cambios que me fueron recomendados]]

El error que se muestra es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "f1"
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
        at Ejercicios.PruebaDivisas.main(PruebaDivisas.java:9)
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, es por que estas intentado arrancar el programa desde la clase ConversorDivisas, debes configurar tu entorno para que se ejecute desde la clase PruebaDivisas. ¿Que IDE estas usando ?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: Yo copie y pegue tu código y no me dio problemas para ejecutar desde el main declarado, guarde el archivo como PruebaDivisas.java, de igual forma es mejor si es que no lo tienes de esa forma. que separes las clases por archivo como dijo @Aitroll y que ademas lo configures como proyecto, para que te sea mas fácil de trabajar. Probé con VS Code 1.44.2

Comment: Hice los cambios que se me han sugerido, y me devuelve otro error...lo agregué en la pregunta...si pudiese revisar por favor...no entiendo pq sigue sin funcionarme. Cuando voy a seleccionar el tipo de cambio es cuando me sale el error

Comment: El error te lo esta marcando, por que cuando te pidió un valor ingresaste f1, lo mas recomendable es usar try/catch para controlar la excepción, ya que debes manejar en caso que se te ingrese un valor que no esperas. Recuerda que ReadLine te retorna un String y luego utilizas Double.parseDouble para obtener el valor como tipo Double, pero este método devolverá una excepción siempre que el String no tenga el formato correcto (números) como indico @VRoxa en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Estas queriendo convertir una cadena "f1" a un tipo numérico por lo que se ve en la excepción.

Tienes dos instancias de tu clase: `ConversorDivisas`, en este caso es: `f1` y `f2`, una de ellas toma por default el valor 0.85, y la otra es a partir del valor que ingreses en el constructor, entonces estas haciendo:

Double.parseDouble(System.console.readline())

y ahí estas poniendo "f1" en  la consola por eso te dice: ey!!!  "f1" no lo puedo convertir a double, entonces solo escribe un número y no f1

Answer (score 1):

En las líneas 9 y 8:

```
double tipo;
tipo = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine());
```

Está esperando la entrada por consola y luego *convertirla* a `double`.
El error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "f1"

... dice precisamente que la cadena `f1` no puede ser convertida a `double`, porque no tiene un formato numérico.

En ese punto, debes pasar por la consola cualquier valor que pueda convertirse a número, 
 *e.g.*: `1`, `2`, `1000`, `1.2`, `-3`, ...

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que dividas las clases por archivos por ejemplo:

```
package Ejercicios;

public class ConversorDivisas {

private double tipoCambio;
public String getTipoCambio;

**//Constructor sin parámetros**
public ConversorDivisas() {
    tipoCambio = 0.85;
}
**//Constructor parametrizado**
public ConversorDivisas(double tc) {
    tipoCambio = tc;
}
public double librasToEuros(double l) {
    return l * tipoCambio; 
}
public double eurosToLibras(double e) {
    return e / tipoCambio;
}
public void setTipoCambio(double tc){
    tipoCambio = tc;
}
public double getTipoCambio(){
    return tipoCambio;
}
}
```

Este código metelo dentro de un archivo que se llame **ConversorDivisas.java** por ejemplo, y el otro codigo dentro del archivo original. Una vez hecho esto ejecutas el archivo que ya tenias generado y que contiene esta linea de codigo --> **class PruebaDivisas {
public static void main(String[] args)** Con eso ya deberias solucionar ese error

Answer (score 0):

Si todo el código esta dentro del mismo archivo, entonces el archivo se debe de llamar `PruebasDivisas.java`. Debe cambiar los accesos de las clases de la siguiente forma:

```
public class PruebaDivisas {
 ...
//resto de código
}

class ConversosDivisas{
 ... //resto de código
}
```

El error se presenta por que en java cuando tienes más de una clase en un mismo archivo, solo debe existir una clase `public` y esta clase es la que debe de tener el método `main`, y adicional el archivo debe de tener el mismo nombre que la clase publica.

Answer (score 0):

He tomado varias de las recomendaciones que te hacen y tocado un poco tu código para que se comporte como creo que quieres que se comporte.

Básicamente agregue un `try/catch` como te recomendé para manejar la excepción en caso que te escriban un valor que no puede parsear a double, también **deje una sola clase publica**, la que tiene el `main`. Quite un atributo de tipo String que no usabas en la clase ConversorDivisas y añadí algunos espacios en tus print de consola.

te dejo el código para que lo compares con el que tienes. Recuerda guardarlo como **PruebaDivisas.java** para que te funcione correctamente.

Espero que te ayude ;)

```
package Ejercicios;

class ConversorDivisas {

    private double tipoCambio;

    //Constructor sin parámetros**
    public ConversorDivisas() {
        tipoCambio = 0.85;
    }
    //Constructor parametrizado**
    public ConversorDivisas(double tc) {
        tipoCambio = tc;
    }
    public double librasToEuros(double l) {
        return l * tipoCambio; 
    }
    public double eurosToLibras(double e) {
        return e / tipoCambio;
    }
    public void setTipoCambio(double tc){
        tipoCambio = tc;
    }
    public double getTipoCambio(){
        return tipoCambio;
    }
}

class PruebaDivisas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double tipo;
        ConversorDivisas f1;
        ConversorDivisas f2;

        System.out.println("Que tipo de cambio quieres?");

        //a partir de aqui comienzan mis dudas**

        try {        
            tipo = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine());
            //con f1 utilizará el tipo de cambio de 0.85.**
            f1 = new ConversorDivisas();

            //con f2 se podrá modificar el tipo de cambio.**
            f2 = new ConversorDivisas(tipo);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException Ex) {
            System.out.println("El valor ingresado no es correcto");
            return;
        }

        double e = 100;
        double l = 100;

        System.out.println("Con el tipo de cambio " + f1.getTipoCambio() + ":");
        System.out.println(e + " euros son " + f1.eurosToLibras(0) + " libras");
        System.out.println(l + " libras " + f1.librasToEuros(0) + " euros");
        System.out.println("Con el tipo de cambio " + f2.getTipoCambio() + ":");
        System.out.println(e + " euros son " + f2.eurosToLibras(0) + " libras");
        System.out.println(l + " libras son " + f2.librasToEuros(0) + " libras");
    }
}
```